# Не выводиться переменная в шаблон.Шаблон отображает "This album is temporarily unavailable"

Tags: python, django

Мой views.py:

```
def galvanic(request):
    images = GalvanicAlbumImage.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'galvanic/galvanicalbum_detail.html', { 'images': images })
```

Мой urls.py:

```
url(r'^galvanic$', galvanic.views.galvanic, name='galvanicalbum')
```

И шаблон galvanicalbum_detail.html:

```
    {% if galvanicalbum.is_visible %}
    <article class="row">
        <header class="col s12 m12 l10 offset-l1">
            <h1>{{ galvanicalbum.title }}</h1>
        </header>
        <section class="col s12 m12 l10 offset-l1">
            <p>{{ galvanicalbum.description }}</p>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    {% for item in images %}
                    <article>
                        <a class="class="col s12 m3" href="javascript:pswpInit({{ forloop.counter0 }});">
                            <img src="{{ item.thumb.url }}" class="responsive-img dpg-album-image" alt="{{ item.alt }}" />
                        </a>
                        <p>
                            {{ item.description }}
                        </p>    
                    </article>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
        <footer class="col s12 m12 l10 offset-l1">
            Created on <time datetime="{{ album.created|date:"Y-m-d" }}">{{ album.created|date:"d M Y" }}</time>
            <p>Tags: {{ album.tags }}</p>
        </footer>
    </article>
{% else %}
    <h3>This album is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
{% endif %}
```

Я все время получаю на странице:

> This album is temporarily unavailable

Из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: Метод `render` в контексте не получает переменной `galvanicalbum`, следовательно `galvanicalbum.is_visible` всегда false

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а что какое значение нужно передавать в этой переменной?

Comment: Подозреваю что задумывалось передавать инстанс `GalvanicAlbum`.  Но тогда наверняка вытягивать нужно не все изображения, а только из конкретного альбома `GalvanicAlbumImage.objects.filter(album_id=some_id)`

Comment: Нет - мне нужно вытянуть именно все изображения из данной модели в template. Если я передаю в render({ 'images': images , 'galvanicalbum': GalvanicAlbum}) - соотвественно на страницу не выводятся galvanicalbum.title и galvanicalbum.description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте переписать view? Наследуйтесь от TemplateView:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .models import GalvanicAlbumImage

class AlbumView(TemplateView):
        template_name = '<html-шаблон>'

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            album_obj = GalvanicAlbumImage.objects.all()

            return {
                'album': album_obj
            }
```